# Laravel groupBy is not working throwing error Syntax error or access violation: 1055

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.6

I have tried solutions in other questions but that is not solving my issue. I have made **strict** from **true** to **false**. Used modes

```
'modes' => [           
    'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',
    'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',
    'NO_ZERO_DATE',
    'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',
    'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER',
    'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
]
```

as well. But I am getting the same error.

```
$orders = Order::orderBy('id', 'desc')->groupBy('order_id')->get();
dd($orders);
```

This is throwing the error

> Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'my_db.orders.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select * from `orders` group by `order_id` order by `id` desc)

(I am using Laravel 5.6)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In *config/database.php*

Change `'strict' => true` To `'strict' => false`
and clear the cache

> php artisan config:cache

OR In MySql settings change

```
mysql > SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

Comment: crap! forgot to run the command. thanks mate. it is working now

Comment: @zahidhasanemon if its correct please upvote and accept

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer**

This is a MySQL issue that can be resolved changing Laravel config as @Rp9 wrote, modifying `strict => true` to `strict => false` in `config/database.php`.

**Long Answer**

MySQL 5.7 introduced something we are calling "strict mode," which is a combination of new modes that, in sum, make MySQL process your queries a little more strictly than before.

"Strict mode" is a list of modes MySQL 5.7 enables by default, comprised of the following modes:

```
ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY
STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
NO_ZERO_IN_DATE
NO_ZERO_DATE
ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO
NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER
NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

So, what if you want to disable / enable just few of this stricts mode? Laravel help us.

```
'connections' => [
    'mysql' => [
        // Ignore this key and rely on the strict key
        'modes' => null,

        // Explicitly disable all modes, overriding strict setting
        'modes' => [],

        // Explicitly enable specific modes, overriding strict setting
        'modes' => [
            'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',
            'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',
        ],
    ]
]
```

Comment: i said i have used these solutions. you are just copying the answers from the other questions. read the question fully first.